# Cannot Update a System Collection Set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, data-collection

I'm trying to tweak the "Server Activity" Data Collection set as outlined in [this blog post](http://itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.com/2015/05/data-collection-making-wait-statistics.html) (I wrote the post, btw. Sorry--it's kinda long). It is working in SQL 2008 R2 and also in SQL 2014.  However, when I run `msdb.dbo.sp_syscollector_update_collection_item` on SQL 2012, I get this error:

> Msg 14696, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   sp_syscollector_update_collection_item, Line 70  Cannot update or
>   delete a system collection set, or add new collection items to it.

Looking at the code of `msdb.dbo.sp_syscollector_update_collection_item`, I see differences between the SQL versions:

**SQL 2008 R2/SQL 2014**

```
IF (@is_system = 1 AND (@new_name IS NOT NULL))
BEGIN
    -- cannot update, delete, or add new collection items to a system collection set
    RAISERROR(14696, -1, -1);
    RETURN (1)
END
```

**SQL 2012**

```
IF (@is_system = 1 AND (@new_name IS NOT NULL OR @parameters IS NOT NULL))
BEGIN
    -- cannot update, delete, or add new collection items to a system collection set
    RAISERROR(14696, -1, -1);
    RETURN (1)
END
```

I'm passing in a non-NULL value for `@parameters`, so I fully understand why I'm getting the error on SQL 2012.

**Questions:**

1. Why is the code different for SQL 2012?
2. Is it safe to manually change the code for `msdb.dbo.sp_syscollector_update_collection_item`?

**Update:** (version numbers for further clarification)

```
Ver     SP  Build Number
--------------------------
2008 R2 SP3 10.50.6000.34
2012    SP2 11.0.5058.0
2014    SP1 12.0.4100.1
```

**Update2:**
I've updated SQL 2012 to SP3 (11.0.6020.0)
The issue persists.

Comment: What service pack and CU level of 2008R2?

Comment: @stacylaray: question has been updated with build numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safe to say the `or @parameters IS NOT NULL` in SQL Server 2012 is a bug.

- SQL Server 2012 v11.0.6260.1 also has the erroneous code.
- SQL Server 2016 v13.0.4446.0 does *not* have that piece.
- SQL Server 2017 v14.0.3025.34 does *not* have that piece.

Furthermore, the code prevents `sp_syscollector_validate_xml` from being called for non-system collection sets.

Since the stored procedure appears to be a system-stored-procedure, you'll likely need to use `sp_MS_marksystemobject` to mark the stored procedure as a system-stored-procedure after you modify it to remove the `or @parameters IS NOT NULL` code.

Be aware that changing procedures that have been shipped by Microsoft may make support more difficult.  I would recommend against making this change on production-critical instances.

For reference, the code as seen in my SQL Server 2012 instance is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_syscollector_update_collection_item]
    @collection_item_id        int = NULL,
    @name                    sysname = NULL,
    @new_name                sysname = NULL,
    @frequency                int = NULL,
    @parameters                xml = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- Security check (role membership)
    IF (NOT (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'dc_operator'), 0) = 1) AND NOT (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'db_owner'), 0) = 1))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(14677, -1, -1, 'dc_operator')
        RETURN(1) -- Failure
    END

    -- Security checks (restrict functionality for non-dc_admin-s)
    IF ((NOT (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'dc_admin'), 0) = 1) AND NOT (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'db_owner'), 0) = 1)) 
        AND (@new_name IS NOT NULL))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(14676, -1, -1, '@new_name', 'dc_admin')
        RETURN (1) -- Failure
    END
    IF ((NOT (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'dc_admin'), 0) = 1) AND NOT (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'db_owner'), 0) = 1))
        AND (@parameters IS NOT NULL))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(14676, -1, -1, '@parameters', 'dc_admin')
        RETURN (1) -- Failure
    END

    DECLARE @retVal int
    EXEC @retVal = dbo.sp_syscollector_verify_collection_item @collection_item_id OUTPUT, @name OUTPUT
    IF (@retVal <> 0)
        RETURN (@retVal)

    IF (@frequency < 5)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @frequency_as_char VARCHAR(36)
        SELECT @frequency_as_char = CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), @frequency)
        RAISERROR(21405, 16, -1, @frequency_as_char, '@frequency', 5)
        RETURN (1)
    END

    IF (LEN(@new_name) = 0)  -- can't rename to an empty string
    BEGIN
      RAISERROR(21263, -1, -1, '@new_name')
      RETURN(1) -- Failure
    END    

    -- Remove any leading/trailing spaces from parameters
    SET @new_name            = LTRIM(RTRIM(@new_name))

    DECLARE @collection_set_name sysname
    DECLARE @is_system              bit
    DECLARE @is_running             bit
    DECLARE @collector_type_uid     uniqueidentifier
    DECLARE @collection_set_id      int
    SELECT @is_running = s.is_running,
           @is_system = s.is_system,
           @collection_set_name = s.name,
           @collector_type_uid = i.collector_type_uid,
           @collection_set_id = s.collection_set_id
    FROM dbo.syscollector_collection_sets s,
         dbo.syscollector_collection_items i
    WHERE s.collection_set_id = i.collection_set_id
    AND i.collection_item_id = @collection_item_id

    IF (@is_system = 1 AND (@new_name IS NOT NULL OR @parameters IS NOT NULL))
    BEGIN
        -- cannot update, delete, or add new collection items to a system collection set
        RAISERROR(14696, -1, -1);
        RETURN (1)
    END

    IF (@parameters IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        EXEC @retVal = dbo.sp_syscollector_validate_xml @collector_type_uid = @collector_type_uid, @parameters = @parameters
        IF (@retVal <> 0)
            RETURN (@retVal)
    END

    -- if the collection item is running, stop it before update
    IF (@is_running = 1)
    BEGIN
        EXEC @retVal = sp_syscollector_stop_collection_set @collection_set_id = @collection_set_id
        IF (@retVal <> 0)
            RETURN(1)
    END

    -- all conditions go, perform the update
    EXEC @retVal = sp_syscollector_update_collection_item_internal     
                            @collection_item_id = @collection_item_id,
                            @name = @name,
                            @new_name = @new_name,
                            @frequency = @frequency,
                            @parameters = @parameters

    -- if you stopped the collection set, restart it
    IF (@is_running = 1)
    BEGIN
        EXEC @retVal = sp_syscollector_start_collection_set @collection_set_id = @collection_set_id
        IF (@retVal <> 0)
            RETURN (1)
    END

    RETURN (0)
END
```

The code in SQL Server 2016 is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_syscollector_update_collection_item]
    @collection_item_id        int = NULL,
    @name                    sysname = NULL,
    @new_name                sysname = NULL,
    @frequency                int = NULL,
    @parameters                xml = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- Security check (role membership)
    IF (NOT (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'dc_operator'), 0) = 1) AND NOT (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'db_owner'), 0) = 1))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(14677, -1, -1, 'dc_operator')
        RETURN(1) -- Failure
    END

    -- Security checks (restrict functionality for non-dc_admin-s)
    IF ((NOT (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'dc_admin'), 0) = 1) AND NOT (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'db_owner'), 0) = 1)) 
        AND (@new_name IS NOT NULL))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(14676, -1, -1, '@new_name', 'dc_admin')
        RETURN (1) -- Failure
    END
    IF ((NOT (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'dc_admin'), 0) = 1) AND NOT (ISNULL(IS_MEMBER(N'db_owner'), 0) = 1))
        AND (@parameters IS NOT NULL))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(14676, -1, -1, '@parameters', 'dc_admin')
        RETURN (1) -- Failure
    END

    DECLARE @retVal int
    EXEC @retVal = dbo.sp_syscollector_verify_collection_item @collection_item_id OUTPUT, @name OUTPUT
    IF (@retVal <> 0)
        RETURN (@retVal)

    IF (@frequency < 5)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @frequency_as_char VARCHAR(36)
        SELECT @frequency_as_char = CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), @frequency)
        RAISERROR(21405, 16, -1, @frequency_as_char, '@frequency', 5)
        RETURN (1)
    END

    IF (LEN(@new_name) = 0)  -- can't rename to an empty string
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(21263, -1, -1, '@new_name')
        RETURN(1) -- Failure
    END    

    -- Remove any leading/trailing spaces from parameters
    SET @new_name            = LTRIM(RTRIM(@new_name))

    DECLARE @collection_set_name sysname
    DECLARE @is_system              bit
    DECLARE @is_running             bit
    DECLARE @collector_type_uid     uniqueidentifier
    DECLARE @collection_set_id      int
    SELECT @is_running = s.is_running,
            @is_system = s.is_system,
            @collection_set_name = s.name,
            @collector_type_uid = i.collector_type_uid,
            @collection_set_id = s.collection_set_id
    FROM dbo.syscollector_collection_sets s,
            dbo.syscollector_collection_items i
    WHERE s.collection_set_id = i.collection_set_id
    AND i.collection_item_id = @collection_item_id

    IF (@is_system = 1 AND (@new_name IS NOT NULL))
    BEGIN
        -- cannot update, delete, or add new collection items to a system collection set
        RAISERROR(14696, -1, -1);
        RETURN (1)
    END

    IF (@parameters IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        EXEC @retVal = dbo.sp_syscollector_validate_xml @collector_type_uid = @collector_type_uid, @parameters = @parameters
        IF (@retVal <> 0)
            RETURN (@retVal)
    END

    -- if the collection item is running, stop it before update
    IF (@is_running = 1)
    BEGIN
        EXEC @retVal = sp_syscollector_stop_collection_set @collection_set_id = @collection_set_id
        IF (@retVal <> 0)
            RETURN(1)
    END

    -- all conditions go, perform the update
    EXEC @retVal = sp_syscollector_update_collection_item_internal     
                            @collection_item_id = @collection_item_id,
                            @name = @name,
                            @new_name = @new_name,
                            @frequency = @frequency,
                            @parameters = @parameters

    -- if you stopped the collection set, restart it
    IF (@is_running = 1)
    BEGIN
        EXEC @retVal = sp_syscollector_start_collection_set @collection_set_id = @collection_set_id
        IF (@retVal <> 0)
            RETURN (1)
    END

    RETURN (0)
END
```